# TFS/Visual Studio Online - Make a query publicly visible

Tags: visual-studio-team-services

I have a query in Visual Studio Online and I want to make it publicly visible (e.g. via a URL that even people not in our team can access).

I know I can share it within team (and know how to do this), but to re-iterate: I want to make it publicly available to people who **don't** have access to the TFS/Visual Studio Online.

Here is the query from Visual Studio Online:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not currently possible to make anything, including a query, public such that anonymous users or users that haven't been added to your account can access it. It is something we have on the backlog for the future.